# Multiple many-to-many relations between two entities

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I have two objects.

**Value:**

```
@Table(name = "random_value")
@Entity(name = "random_value")
public class RandomValue
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "random_value", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    public RandomValue()
    {
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And **Entity**:

```
@Table(name = "entity")
@Entity(name = "entity")
public class Entity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "entity_value_list", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<RandomValue> values;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "hidden_entity_value_list", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<RandomValue> hiddenValues;

    public Entity()
    {
    }

    public List<RandomValue> getValues()
    {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<RandomValue> values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public List<RandomValue> getHiddenValues()
    {
        return values;
    }

    public void setHiddenValues(List<RandomValue> hiddenValues)
    {
        this.hiddenValues = hiddenValues;
    }
}
```

I also have four tables:

One for **Value**:

```
CREATE TABLE `random_value`
(
    `id`  INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `random_value` VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

One for **Entity**:

```
CREATE TABLE `entity`
(
    `id`      INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And two tables to have many to many relationship

```
CREATE TABLE `entity_value_list`
(
    `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `values_id`  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`, `values_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `entity_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`)
            REFERENCES `entity` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `values_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`values_id`)
            REFERENCES `random_value` (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `hidden_entity_value_list`
(
    `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `values_id`  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`, `values_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `entity_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`)
            REFERENCES `entity` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `values_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`values_id`)
            REFERENCES `random_value` (`id`)
);
```

When I try to run my spring boot project that uses hibernate and h2 database that's created on runtime I get an error saying.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "ENTITY_ID" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE `hidden_entity_value_list`
(
    `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `values_id`  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`, `values_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `entity_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`)
            REFERENCES `entity` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `values_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`values_id`)
            REFERENCES `random_value` (`id`)
); [90045-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:576) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

From what I understand because fields in the `hidden_entity_value_list` look like those in `entity_value_list` it is complaining. How do I go around that and make this whole thing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint names must be unique schema wide.

You have the CONSTRAINT name `entity_id` used in both tables. So simply rename on of the two.